Unable to render HTML in a view
I have a view that includes HTML from a rich text field. Im trying to render the HTML in a twig template but it does not work. Tried {{ output | raw }} also autoescape.
Here's how it looks in the Inspector

Any ideas how I can render this?

I'm not aware of issues with rendering rich text fields in Views. Can you add more details?

First, you need to remove the <p> tag that is coming from the Drupal view. Then, you can apply your HTML code in this view.

@VishalKumarYadav thanks - but that's the issue. That black  tag is the item that should be rendered.
